# Build latest llvm-project as rpm for redhat

Tags: cmake, llvm, rpm

I am trying to build the latest llvm-project currently the version 12 as an rpm on redhat.

CMake allows me to create a src.rpm from the llvm-project but how can i build a binary rpm?

Answer (score 0):

When you have src.rpm you can build a binary package using:

```
$ mock -r fedora-34-x86_64 your.src.rpm
```

List of possible targets can be determined using `ls /etc/mock/*`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! On redhat there is no /etc/mock

Comment: You have to install `mock` package from EPEL.